# ¿como puedo tomar el valor de una fila de una tabla html haciendo click en la fila y enviar esos datos a unos input text?

Tags: javascript

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La tabla la genera dinamicamente con un arreglo.

pero no tengo idea como hacer esto, por favor me pueden ayudar, gracias.

```
<table class="table table-dark table-hover table-bordered container container-fluid order-table" id="listaPacientes" name="listaPacientes">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col">No. Exp.</th>
                            <th scope="col">Nombre</th>
                            <th scope="col">Apellido Paterno</th>
                            <th scope="col">Apellido Materno</th>
                            <th scope="col">Fecha Nacimiento</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="data">


                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Puede usar los eventos Onclick de JavaScript, al crear tu tabla añade uno a tu `<tr>`, ademas agrega un Id a cada `<tr>`, en tu método de JavaScript vas a recuperar todos los hijos de ese `<tr>` y los vas a ir añadiendo a tus inputs

```
<table class="table table-dark table-hover table-bordered container container-fluid order-table" id="listaPacientes" name="listaPacientes">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">No. Exp.</th>
            <th scope="col">Nombre</th>
            <th scope="col">Apellido Paterno</th>
            <th scope="col">Apellido Materno</th>
            <th scope="col">Fecha Nacimiento</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="data">
        <tr id="1" onclick="tr_to_input(this)">
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Felipe</td>
            <td>Niño</td>
            <td>Castro</td>
            <td>2022-07-22</td>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

En su función de JavaScript haría lo siguiente:

```
<script>
function tr_to_input(row)
{
    //Obtiene los objetos de los inputs
    var input_exp =  document.getElementById("exp");
    var input_nombre = document.getElementById("nom");
    var input_apepat = document.getElementById("apepat");
    var input_apemat = document.getElementById("apemat");
    var input_nacimiento = document.getElementById("nacimiento");
    //Obtiene todos los hijos del <tr>
    var row_data = row.childNodes;
    //Asigna los valores de los hijos a los valores de los inputs
    input_exp.value = row_data.childNodes[0].value;
    input_nombre.value = row_data.childNodes[1].value;
    input_apepat.value = row_data.childNodes[2].value;
    input_apemat.value = row_data.childNodes[3].value;
    input_nacimiento.value = row_data[4].value;
}
</script>
```

Y asumiendo que tiene un formulario con los `<input>` que comenta:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exp" placeholder="No. Exp.">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nom" placeholder="Nombre">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="apepat" placeholder="Apellido Paterno">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="apemat" placeholder="Apellido Materno">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nacimiento" placeholder="Fecha Nacimiento">
</form>
```